# How to get union of two tables with different alias

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want get union but want to show one column twice with different alias.
E.g

```
Select a as first from table1 
union 
select a as second from table1
```

it shows first as output.

But I want to show both first and second. How can it be achieved in MSSQL?

Comment: Please add example data, expected output and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: @juergend I am asking about column not about data please read question.

Comment: Union is the wrong operation for this sort of thing. Do you want something more like `select a as first, a as second from table1`?

Comment: If you want to have a good answer you have to provide more than just a sentence. But if you don't show any effort then don't expect to get some in return.

Comment: @Jaloopa you are right I am looking for something like this but can't achieve in this way I need something like union

Comment: @juergend I am having query which is on 13 pages. so that's why I just put a little sample here.

Comment: Union combines the results from two queries into one set of columns. There's no way to make the column name change halfway down. The closest I can think of is `select a as first, null as second from table1 union all select null as first, a as second from table1`

Comment: @Jaloopa Awsome please answer your comment I will mark it as an answer. you made it man...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Union combines the results from two queries into one set of columns. There's no way to make the column name change halfway down. The closest I can think of is

```
select a as first
, null as second 
from table1 

union all 

select null as first
, a as second 
from table1
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have all rows with `union all`

```
Select a as first from table1 
union all 
select a as second from table1
```

Comment: @MuhammadRizwanShahid A query always can return only one table. You will not see two columns! Union takes only alias from first query!

Comment: Thats what I am asking so tell me if union is not suitable here then how it can be achieve???

Answer (score 1):

If I've got it right:

```
Select a as first,a as second from table1
```